# NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android, android-studio, numberformatexception

Android studio show me error in event log
NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 10
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile files('libs/gdata-base-1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdata-calendar-2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdata-calendar-meta-2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdata-client-1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdata-contacts-3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdata-contacts-meta-3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdata-core-1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdata-maps-2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdata-maps-meta-2.0.jar')
}
```

IDE fatal errors show me someting like this:

This exception in plugin Android Support.

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1  at
>   com.android.sdklib.repository.FullRevision.parseRevisionImpl(FullRevision.java:198)
>     at
>   com.android.sdklib.repository.FullRevision.parseRevision(FullRevision.java:127)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.repository.SdkMavenRepository.getHighestInstalledVersion(SdkMavenRepository.java:179)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.lint.checks.GradleDetector.checkLocalMavenVersions(GradleDetector.java:1092)
>     ...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after SDK update. 
In my case the solution was to remove 24.0.0-alpha1 folder from sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7 and to delete `<version>24.0.0-alpha1</version>` line from sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

In `build.gradle` of Project (not module) i changed the classpath.

It now looks like this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

> What i have did to work this fine is updated android studio to latest
>   release and updated gradle.also did following changes in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Actually Svetlana Kuleshova tried to mention was

try with below procedure

[image]

and comment the maven pom.xml or maven-metadata.xml

24.0.0-alpha1 -->

Answer (score -1):

Try this cases if you really need 24.0.0-alpha1:

1. Replace

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.2'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
   ```

to

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-alpha1'
```

2. Launch stanalone SDK manager and load Android N, API 23, N preview,
   after that you need replace

   ```
   compileSdkVersion 23
   ```

to

```
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
```

Tell me if it work for you too.

Comment: and i still have error  NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1

Comment: @AlexeyPecherey ive tried your solution but not worked for me :(

Comment: i.e. let's do some random replacement!