# exception :NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1 Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

> NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1,,,

What am I am doing wrong here? Why this exception comes?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.fblogin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

Comment: do you have  24.0.0-alpha1 anywhere

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35982333/1754112

Comment: No i don't have used 24.0.0-alpha1 .Some said its the new version of v7 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'

Comment: @TalhaMir none of the solution specified there solve this issue.Can u help regarding this.?